# Reverse Data With BIT TYPE for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a column using a `BIT` type (1/0). I have some records are set to 1 and some are set to 0. Those are record flag needs to be reversed. So basically, I want all records with 1 set 0, and all records with 0 set to 1.

If I run

```
Update Table1 Set Flag = 1 Where Flag = 0
```

first, then I am afraid all record flags will be 1 now, and will not able to know which ones are flag = 0.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: don't you have any primary key identifier for your table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To negate the value of all `bit` fields do it in one operation. You can use a `CASE`

```
UPDATE table1
SET    flag = CASE flag
                WHEN 1 THEN 0
                WHEN 0 THEN 1
              END
```

Or [Bitwise Exclusive OR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190277.aspx)

```
UPDATE table1
SET    flag = flag ^ 1
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a way you can do it without a CASE statement, using a bitwise operator instead:

```
update Table1
set flag = ~flag
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 [`NOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173468.aspx) would be more intuitive than `XOR` here.

Answer (score 2):

There's the simple arithmetic:

```
update table1
  set Flag = 1 - Flag
```

Martin Smith's second answer can be reduced to a somewhat more obscure:

```
update table1
  set Flag ^= 1
```

Great for the keystroke challenged, but I don't think it improves on readability, maintainability or performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try following Query :

```
update table1
set flag = case when flag = 1 then 0 else 1 end
```

It will definitely solve your problem .

Comment: please vote up if my ans help you . it will help to increase my reputation . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 Update table1 
  Set flag = Case flag 
      When 1 then 0 
      Else 1 End
```